# How to capture the output of stdout in python in batches?

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a python command from another module which upon invocation will print out 23 million lines. I was wondering if there was a way to do something like:

```
function_call_here() 
for every 100,000 lines of output to stdout 
    store output as a list of 100,000 strings
    pickle output 
    save as "output_XXXX" where XXXX is an identifier (i.e.,0015 if on batch 15)
    print "read batch X"
```

I realize this is just pseudocode, but I would appreciate help with this!